# If a list is empty will it throw an exception while applying.contains of a formatted date

Tags: java, list

```
 List<String> Lst = List;
 Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(); 
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    if(null == Lst){
                Lst = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    if(!Lst .contains(df.format(today.getTime()))) {
            System.out.println("...");
    }
```

will this throw an exception if Lst is empty?

Comment: Have you tried to run that?

Comment: No, your codes won't throw exception. The codes won't be compiled

Comment: When the Lst is null then only there might be NullPointerException, Otherwise without a null and empty check I can directly use if(!Lst .contains(df.format(today.getTime()))) piece of code, right?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also I would suggest a list of `LocalDate` objects rather than strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code won´t throw an exception if you call contains on an empty List. The only time you will receive an exception is in case the list was not initialised (NullPointerException).

Anyways the code in your snippet won´t compile if you have no "List" - List instance available the rest of your code because of the first line.

Comment: List is a method variable that's y didn't mentioned in piece of code....

Comment: Then you are fine. The answer  is that you won´t get an exception by calling contains if its initialised and only otherwise a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

I should like to contribute the modern version of your code:

```
    List<LocalDate> lst = null;

    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Ashkhabad"));
    if (lst == null) {
        lst = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    System.out.println("Contains today? " + lst.contains(today));
    System.out.println("Empty? " + lst.isEmpty());
```

Please enter your desired time zone where I put Asia/Ashkhabad. The code just printed:

```
Contains today? false
Empty? true
```

So no, there was no exception thrown. And the list *was* empty.

Another way to find out would be to read the documentation. For `List.contains` it says:

> Returns `true` if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns `true` if and only if this list contains at least
>   one element `e` such that `Objects.equals(o, e)`.

The empty list does not contain such an element, so we should expect `false` to be returned. To be sure, read on:

> **Throws:**
>
> `ClassCastException` - if the type of the specified element is
>   incompatible with this list (optional)
>
> `NullPointerException` - if the specified element is null and this
>   list does not permit null elements (optional)

If the list were to throw any exception if it were empty, it would have been mentioned here if nowhere else. It isn’t. So the list must not throw any exception when it is empty and you test `contains`.

### java.time

I said I gave you the modern version of your code. The classes you used, `Calendar`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, are long outdated and poorly designed. Instead I used `LocalDate` from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. And while holding `Calendar` objects in your list would have been problematic because the criteria for equality are both strict and complicated, having a list of `LocalDate` objects is advantageous. A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day, so equality is simple: two such objects are equal if they denote the same day. Did I remember to say that `java.time` is so much nicer to work with compared to the old classes?

### Links

- [Documentation of `List.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/Y");

        if(myList.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("List Empty");
        }
        myList.add(0,"08/04/2018");

        System.out.println("Date Format ::" + myList.get(0));
```